# Extracting url based on headers with curl

Tags: php, curl

I want to give a url with curl..and fetch it based on its header attribute Expires.

I want to retrieve the page only if it was cached in the last 30 days.

Two things that I think arent right...

1) The  gmmktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1998).. I am not sure how to set it to today - 30 days ago. 
2)  Whether it will return me google based on its headers? what the $page variable will be if the url has no cached headers with date older than 30 days

```
 function exractURl()
   {
       //How to convert gmmktime to the last 30 days from today
       $ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1998)) . " GMT";
       $c=  curl_init('http://www.google.co.il/');
       curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expires:'.$ts));
      //  What output will page give me..if the headers arent found
       $page= curl_exec($c);
       curl_close($c);
   }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
   function exractURl()
   {
       $ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", strtotime("30 days ago")) . " GMT";
       $c=  curl_init('http://www.google.co.il/');
       curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('If-Modified-Since:'.$ts));
       $page= curl_exec($c);
       curl_close($c);
       return $page;
   }
```

Comment: I think the expires-header is something for a response, not a request.  You could sent a "If-Modified-Since"-header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `If-Modified-Since` to ask the server to only return the content if it has changed (Otherwise you'll get a `304 Not Modified` response). Of course this relies on the server behaving. See here for more details: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

And to answer your question on how to get the time as of 30 days ago, you can use the ever convenient [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", strtotime("30 days ago")) . " GMT";
```

Comment: What abou thte time.. is it okay..how do I deal with it?

Comment: is there an if statement that I can include to identify that 304 response.? is it a string that contains the words :"304 Not Modified"

Comment: lol..I got the whole page returned... I wonder when I dont get a response...see update above

Comment: How can I test the statement to make it produce 304? reduce time perhaps?...strange, it doesnt work, even when I put now in the strtotime..

Comment: lol..with this link I get no response..if I put it inside the code:http://www.sexygreg.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sexygreg.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1